# Python3. Setuptools. Adding a local package to an assembly

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, setuptools

There is a locally built package (eg **main-0.1.tar.gz**). There is another package (for example **base-0.1**) that requires **main-0.1** as a dependency.

It is necessary that during the subsequent installation of the **base-0.1** package, the **main-0.1** package is also installed.

Those. You can specify only packages with **PyPI** in **install_requires**, but local adding packages to the assembly is not clear how.

You can add the package **main-0.1.tag.gz** to the **base-0.1** archive using **MANIFEST.in** (`include main-0.1.tag.gz`). But further **dependency_links**, for example, does not work correctly.

How do I add a local package to the build of another package and then install it along with another package, as if it were pulled from **PyPI**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at:

- [*PEP 440* ("*File URLs*")](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#file-urls)
- [*PEP 508*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#examples)

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    # [...]
    install_requires = [
        'main @ file:///path/to/main-0.1.tar.gz'
        # [...]
    ],
)
```

---

Alternatively (probably better actually), use some combination of [`pip install` options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options):

```
pip install --no-index --find-links '/path/to/distributions' main base
```

Reference:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages

Comment: This should be the answer instead of messing up with `MANIFEST.in`. @photon if a local installation is required, just use `pip install -e` with paths for everything and push to some package index (even local one deployed e.g. via Docker). Less mess, better code.

Comment: @PeterBadida, After assembly, when in the end there will be an archive `package.tar.gz`. For example, I will copy it to another computer and run `pip install package.tar.gz`. There will be no dependent package. It needs to be added to the assembly, as I wrote, through **MANIFEST.in**?

Comment: _assembly_ is not a concept that exists in the _Python_ world. Would you mind clarifying what you are trying to achieve (preferrably by rewriting your question).

Comment: @photon You're just treating a Python package dist as an ordinary archive and this way you only break the logic on multiple places. There will be no package installed correctly just because you embed a tar into tar afaik nor is it supposed to be treated that way. If you really need to have tars e.g. for non-Internet installation, make valid package dist for each package and then package those into one tar with instructions e.g. `pip install ./*.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a rough solution. I don't know how much it is for Feng Shui, but it works.

Add `include main-0.1.tar.gz` to **MANIFEST.in**

In **setup.py**, at the end of the file (after calling setup ()), add:

```
if 'sdist' not in sys.argv[1]:
    os.system('pip install main-0.1.tar.gz')
```

The condition may be different if, for example, `sdist` is not used for building (`python setup.py sdist`). The main thing is to somehow determine that this is running `setup` for assembly, and not for installation (`pip install base-0.1.tar.gz` in the future).

In this case, we copy the local dependent package into the archive of the package being built, and it is distributed, accordingly, along with it. And installed the same way.